# For an online platform count the number of students with perfect score

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I recently gave test on codility platform and was stuck on below SQL question.

**Question**: For an online platform assessments were conducted for 3 topics and scores were provided.

Table: Assessments

Input:

```
|Id|experience|sql|algo|bug_fixing|
|1 |5         |100|null|100       |
|2 |1         |100|100 |null      |
|3 |3         |100|null|50        |
|4 |5         |100|null|50        |
|5 |5         |100|100 |100       |
```

We need to print experience, count of students having a perfect score(null is considered a perfect score) as max and count of students with that year of experience as counts. Results to be printed in descending order of years of experience.

Output:

```
|experience|max|counts|
|5         |2  |3     |
|3         |0  |1     |
|1         |1  |1     |
```

My solution:

```
With t1 as
(select experience, 
 count(experience) as max 
 from assessments 
 where (sql=100 or sql=null) 
 and (algo=100 or algo=null) 
 and (bug_fixing=100 or bug_fixing=null) 
group by experience) 

select a.experience,
t1.max, 
count(a.experience) as counts 
from assessments a join t1 on a.experience=t1.experience 
group by a.experience
```

However, I am getting incorrect count in output for second column(max).

Can someone tell me error or correction needed in my code? TIA.

Comment: nullability check can not be done with '=' sign, it has to be with is null or is not null condition

Comment: Thanks for this. Got the desired result.
The correct code is:


With t1 as
(select experience, 
 count(experience) as max 
 from assessment 
 where (sql=100 or sql is null) 
 and (algo=100 or algo is null) 
 and (bug_fixing=100 or bug_fixing is null) 
group by experience) 

select a.experience,
coalesce(t1.max,0), 
count(a.experience) as counts 
from assessment a left join t1 on a.experience=t1.experience 
group by a.experience,t1.max;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need subqueries or `with` statements. Use the aggregate with `filter` option, e.g.:

```sql
select 
    experience,
    count(*) filter (where 
        coalesce(sql, 100)+ 
        coalesce(algo, 100)+ 
        coalesce(bug_fixing, 100) = 300
    ) as max,
    count(*)
from assessments
group by experience
order by experience desc
```

Test it in [db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=bd72f11dbacf2a28a7b38e4f9215a965)

Read more [in the documentation.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES)

Comment: Amazing, thanks. Never used filter option so wasn't aware. Thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

```
With t1 as
(select experience, 
 count(experience) as max 
 from assessment 
 where (sql=100 or sql is null) 
 and (algo=100 or algo is null) 
 and (bug_fixing=100 or bug_fixing is null) 
group by experience) 

select a.experience,
coalesce(t1.max,0), 
count(a.experience) as counts 
from assessment a left join t1 on a.experience=t1.experience 
group by a.experience,t1.max;
```

Answer (score 0):

Kudos to @klin as I was unaware about `filter`clause before this. Below is my solution with CASE statement:

```
    select 
    experience,
     sum(case when
        coalesce(sql, 100)+ 
        coalesce(algo, 100)+ 
        coalesce(bug_fixing, 100) = 300 Then 1 Else 0 End
    ) as max,
    count(exp) as count
from assessments
group by experience
order by experience desc
```